# Get date for every Thursday in the year Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

Given a day of the week (*var day*) the code below will print the date of each 
day in the year starting from today. Since 4 = Thursday, I will get a list 
of all the Thursdays left in the year. I was just curious if there was some 
'neater' way to accomplish this?

```
var day = 4;
var date = new Date();
var nextYear = date.getFullYear() + 1;

while(date.getDay() != day)
{
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)    
}

while(date.getFullYear() < nextYear)
{
    var yyyy = date.getFullYear();

    var mm = (date.getMonth() + 1);
    mm = (mm < 10) ? '0' + mm : mm;

    var dd = date.getDate();
    dd = (dd < 10) ? '0' + dd : dd;

    console.log(yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd)

    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
}
```

**Output:**

2011-02-10

2011-02-17

2011-02-24

2011-03-03

2011-03-10

..etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it would look a lot prettier if you used [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/).

```
var thursday = Date.today().next().thursday(),
    nextYear = Date.next().january().set({day: 1}),
    format = 'yyyy-MM-dd';

while (thursday.isBefore(nextYear))
{
    console.log(thursday.toString(format));
    thursday = thursday.add(7).days();
}
```

See also http://code.google.com/p/datejs/.

Comment: @alpha: me too. Unfortunately, development seems to have completely halted on it...

Comment: @Matt: Yeah. :(
I thought of taking it over myself, but I'm pretty busy.

Comment: I found this (https://github.com/bigfix/datejs) though Google, and it's a bit newer, but it seems the only changes were to the syntactic sugar and not the core.

Comment: @alpha123, @Matt: What is missing from Datejs that you want adding?

Comment: @Tim: my concerns are primarily in the [open issues](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/issues/list). Other than that, the NLP is pretty good but not ideal; documentation is also a bit weird in places (not very well unified cf. jQuery, YUI). Are you a contributor?

Comment: @Tim: The parsing can be very fragile at times and in general could use some improvement (e.g. it accepts 'day after tomorrow' but not 'the day after tomorrow' which seems more natural).

Comment: @Matt, @alpha123: I'm not a contributor to Datejs and have no particular interest in being one. It just occurred to me that it could be that it's finished and does what it does with no issues, and I was too lazy to check their site or issue tracker.

Comment: Datejs looks pretty interesting, it wouldn't make sense to include another javascript library for my simple need above, but I may consider it in a future project, thanks for the recommendation!